# Mod rewrite including punctuation?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I've come across a bug in my site: basically, it won't allow page names with full stops (periods) in them. I know the root of the problem is in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2&split=$3 [L]
```

Here the regex will not match anything with a period, this is intentional if a user is trying to directly access a file.

Here are some examples of common URLs.

```
games/Spider:+The+Secret+of+Bryce+Manor
games/Orbital
features/Interviewed:+Dennis+Sijnen+from+No+Monkeys
news/all/4
```

The `split` portion of the URL is usually only used for pagination. The `page` portion of the URL is where I would want to place full stops, for example:

```
games/Must.Eat.Birds
```

As I'm not particularly good at either mod rewrite or regex I'd just like a solution that allows full stops. I know it could potentially be a more complex regex and here I'm out of my depth.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you need to give some examples of URLs that you want rewritten (and what they should become) and URLs that should not be rewritten.  The simple answer is to remove `\.` from your regexps.  What problems does that cause?

Comment: Sorry cjm, I've done that now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simons response will solve your problem, just replace the "page" portion with `[^/]` instead of `[^/\.]` which btw, you don't need to escape periods in sets.

A little bit of mod_rewrite magic you may be interested in based on the text of your question:   This portion of rewrite will match any real files, links, or directories in your DocumentRoot - if this happens first, it wont match your later rules - therefore ensuring `/css/main.css` goes to the real file.  Then anything else gets rewritten and dumped into index.php.

```
# -s = File Exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
# -l = Is a SymLink
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# -d = Is a Directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# if we match any of the above conditions - serve the file.
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# adding your rules with the slight modifications pointed out above and by simon.
# only allows '.' in the "page" portion.
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2&split=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Indeed, Simon's answer doesn't take into account real files, which was one of my concerns in the first place. Thanks very much. :-)

Comment: dosen't `[^/.]` mean "match all characters that aren't '/' or *any character (.)*?

Comment: The `.` in a set (`[]`) is just a `.`, test for yourself

Answer (score 2):

Replace every `[^/\.]` with `[^/]` -- that way they will match everything that is not a '/' instead of everything that is not a '/' and not a '.'

If you don't want to allow dots at certain positions just don't change the old regex at those locations.