# Removing trailing slashes with mod rewrite?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

This relates to my previous question (which can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352425/mod-rewrite-including-punctuation)). I'd like to be able to remove the trailing slash from the URL so that it doesn't mess up certain areas of my site. The .htaccess code is here:

```
# -s = File Exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
# -l = Is a SymLink
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# -d = Is a Directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# if we match any of the above conditions - serve the file.
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# only allows '.' in the "page" portion.
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2&split=$3 [L]
```

As before, I'm out of my depth with this, so can anyone help out?

Comment: Am I right in thinking it's the regex you're having trouble with?

Comment: I suggested migrating this to serverfault where there are probably a lot more Apache admins.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you're asking. Doesn't your .htaccess already remove the slashes?

Comment: The page served will be the same, but if the trailing slash is present then relative URIs will change. I.e a relative link from /page/etc to ./melon will be fine, linking to /page/melon, but /page/etc/ to ./melon will link to /page/etc/melon.

Comment: I don't think you can change what is shown in the address bar, which in turn means that whatever rewrites are done serverside, a link will always go from `/page/etc/` to `/page/etc/melon`. You've got to rewrite the target server-side, I think.

Why is there a dot before the slash: `./melon`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

As the other already omit the trailing slash.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [NC,L]
```

Here's what I see in the logs (abbreviated):

```
applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'host/'
rewrite 'host/' -> 'host'
```

So that seems OK to me.

Comment: You should better use a permanent redirect than just an internal rewrite.