# Removing Trailing Slash with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, trailing-slash

I am trying yo remove the trail slash from an url with this pattern

http://localhost/~francesco/mycms/about/

to make it

http://localhost/~francesco/mycms/about

I have tried lots of rules but no one is working for me.

My rewrite rule is this by now

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~francesco/mycms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368276/removing-trailing-slashes-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: I' not working, i'm sorry.  http://pastebin.com/847u3vac

Answer (score 1):

Try placing this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(about)/$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

just after

> RewriteBase /~francesco/mycms/

If you want to work for any first level directory following the RewriteBase  i.e. `http://localhost/~francesco/mycms/[anything-here]/` use

```
#exclude the /~francesco/mycms/admin/directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: It works fine until i try to access the /admin directory, it tells safari cannot access the server, if i put it after the if clauses, it works fine to access the admin, but don't work with or without the final slash

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni what is url for admin: `http://localhost/~francesco/mycms/admin/`?

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni I added the exclusion rule above