# How can I remove index.html using ".htaccess"?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect this link:

```
domain/error/index.html
```

To

```
domain/error/
```

How can I do that?

Another question:

I want to remove the last forward slash in this link:

```
domain/category.php?id=41/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both of these things using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), provided that it is enabled for and included with your version of Apache.

For your first question, you may want to look into the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive if index.html recently changed to another location. The following would be valid:

```
Redirect    domain/error/index.html domain/error/
```

For the second question I would do something like this:

```
RewriteRule    domain/category.php?id=(\d*)/ domain/category.php?id=$1
```

The difference between the two is that `Redirect` makes the client submit a new request, while `RewriteRule` will modify the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 : user the DirectoryIndex directive from Apache :-
 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html has example you can cut and paste.

Question 2: Look [mod_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one)
and [Removing trailing slashes with mod rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368276/removing-trailing-slashes-with-mod-rewrite)